# Android Client can't open python server over LAN

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

I couldn't find anything about this problem,
I want to make simple communication between python server running on a pc and android client, I tested it with simple java program and it worked well but in android it's not binding socket..
Here is my python code:

```
 import socket    
 soc=socket.socket();
 port=20042
 soc.bind(('192.168.1.5',port))
 soc.listen(5)
 while True:
     conn, addr=soc.accept()
     print("Got connection from",addr)
     temp=conn.recv(1024)
     msg=temp.decode('utf-8')
     print buffer1
     print len(buffer1)
     print(msg[2:7])
     if (msg[2:7]=="Hello"):
        print("Behtareen SAAB")

     else:
        print("Ponka! chal phutta kha."
```

and here is my android code:

```
 public void startServer1()
  {

      b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              Toast.makeText(socketSocket.this, "Starting Commnication",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              try {
                String  host = "192.168.1.5";

                  Toast.makeText(socketSocket.this, "1",
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

//it work till here, "1" is toasted and then go to exception.

```
                  final Socket soc;
                  final int port = 20042;
                  final int timeout = 30000;

                  soc=new Socket();
                  soc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);

                  Toast.makeText(socketSocket.this, "2",
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  DataOutputStream dout = new     DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
                  dout.writeUTF("shal oe");
                  dout.flush();
                  dout.close();
                  soc.close();

              } catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  Toast.makeText(socketSocket.this, "ponka",
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }
      });}
```

Comment: By the way i have add internet permission line in Manifest and also checked that firewall is not blocking the comm. I ran python server and then from android web browser when i entered http://192.168.1.5:20042, and it makes coommunication then i realized that firewall is not blocking it..

Comment: 'public void startServer1()'. Why are you calling that start server? It seems you are starting a client there.

Comment: You will have at least a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Look in your logs.

Comment: 'Toast.makeText(socketSocket.this, "ponka",
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();'. What ponka? You should replace that string by e.getMessage(). Use that message!

Comment: buddy "Ponka" is just a string i want to see if it goes to exception.

Comment: public void startServer1() is just an function name i created,, you are right it should be start client :-), but that's not a problem, problem isthat its not starting socket..